# Javascript filter array in separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and in array each id have a text like `region, province, location or city` and it's string like below :

```
 ["region43","region63","location23","region86","location63","province25","province12","city64","city98","province90"]
```

How can I filter that in 4 separate arrays without text and string like :

For province text array should be :

```
  [25,12,90]
```

For city text array should be:

```
  [64,98]
```

For location text array should be:

```
 [23,63]
```

For region text array should be:

```
  [43,63,86]
```

Comment: What do you mean "without key like", what do you have then? What do you want to get?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey stop down voting!  If you spent more than 5 seconds reading the question and observating the code you would understand what he means.

Comment: i want to remove text from array like `region43` => `43`

Comment: Amirali, you would use the `for loop` and `regex` and `split` from `strings` to achieve your goal.  I'm sorry that the stackoveflow police were unable to comprehend your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` and `reduce` like this:

```js
var data = ["region43","region63","location23","region86","location63","province25","province12","city64","city98","province90"];

var result = data.map( s => s.split(/(\d+)/) )
      .reduce ( (o, [key,val]) => (o[key] = (o[key] || []).concat(+val), o), {} );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can get one of the individual arrays as follows:

```
result['province'] // [25,12,90]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression and split the string in not numbers and number part. For the result, I suggest to use an object for collecting. Later, you could use an assignment, like

```
region = result.region;
```

for a single type.

```js
var data = ["region43", "region63", "location23", "region86", "location63", "province25", "province12", "city64", "city98", "province90"],
    result = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var m = a.match(/(\D+)(\d+)/);
    result[m[1]] = result[m[1]] || [];
    result[m[1]].push(m[2]);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: while this is a very good answer, he did specfically ask for `arrays`.  Could you perhaps include an `array` method as the default answer and an `object` answer as the suggested best practice.  Some people are just more confortable with arrays.